# Styling <button> with <i> icon and text in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have `<button>` tag that have `<i>` element for displaying icon before text.

Here's the HTML

```
<button>
    <i></i>
    Login Using Facebook
</button>
```

the inside `<i>` is for displaying icon. Usually for other tag like `<a>`, I can just use `:before` pseudo-class to display icon, but it seems I can not do this for `<button>` tags.

and here's the CSS

```
button {
    background: #4a6ea9;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 24px;
    border: 1px solid #4a6ea9;
    vertical-align: top;
}
button i {
    background: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/danleech/simple/24/facebook-icon.png');
    display: inline-block;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    border-right: 1px dotted #fff;
}
```

Here's the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/petrabarus/SDh3M

The first initial display in my Chrome 28.0.1500.95 for Linux is like below

[image]

looks a little bit imbalance on the top and bottom (I'm not a designer nor I am a front-end engineer but I can just sense that it's quite imbalance), so I can simply add padding `padding: 4px 6px 1px 6px;` and then it looks more balanced like below in my Chrome (does it look different in yours?)

[image]

although, I don't know why the tag seems to add padding for the icon and the text. I set the icon's size to 24x24px and the text's `line-height` to 24px but the final height of the button is 32px. Is it possible to remove the padding?

And the biggest problem is in the Firefox (my version is 17.0.1 for Linux), the text seems to be displayed near to the bottom and it looks so imbalance

[image]

the padding addition to fix the Chrome's makes it even worse for the Firefox's.

[image]

Is it possible to make it look exactly the same in both browsers (and pretty much for other modern browsers like Opera and Safari)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below css.

```
button i {
    background: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/danleech/simple/24/facebook-icon.png") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right: 1px dotted #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left; /*New Edit*/
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
}
```

Comment: ah awesome! looks great in firefox and chrome.

Comment: is there any explanation why it seems to put a lot of bottom padding when it was `display: inline-block`?

Comment: "The Ghost Gap?" - http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ might help.